# Feedback Request: HID USB to Bluetooth Relay

Tags: bluetooth, usb, arduino-mini, keyboard

Bluetooth Relay Project:

> Develop a USB to bluetooth adapter for my mechanical keyboard. Using a USB host shield, have an Arduino Pro Mini read keyboard usb commands and repeat them over bluetooth.

I have minimal experience with Arduino and circuitry, from my perspective this project seems pretty straight forward plug and play of the hardware components.

I plan to use the following hardware:

Hardware:

- Arduino

  - Arduino Pro Mini 328 - 3.3V/8MHz
  - [Sparkfun Products: 11114](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11114)
- Bluetooth HID module

  - BlueSMiRF HID
  - [Sparkfun Product: 10938](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) ($25)
- USB Host Shield

  - USB Host Shield for Arduino Pro Mini
  - [circuitsathome](https://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-for-arduino-pro-mini/) ($20)
- Power Source

  - USB Phone power block
  - Output: 5v 1000mA

Total Cost: $55

I will be connecting the USB module by following the write up [here](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?p=3310)) and will be connecting the USBHost shield by following this [guide](https://www.circuitsathome.com/usb-host-shield-hardware-manual) and this [guide](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_USBHostShield.html)

**Does anyone have any comments/suggestions/concerns/words of wisdom before I start to order stuff?**